# Optimizate My SQL Index Multiple Table JOIN

Tags: mysql, database, join, indexing

I have a 5 tables in mysql. And when I want execute query it executed too long.
There are structure of my tables:

1. Reciept(count rows: 23799640)[reciept table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/214FL.png)
2. reciept_goods(count rows: 39398989)[reciept_goods table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jQUQ.png)
3. good(count rows: 17514)[good table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQ2xv.png)
4. good_categories(count rows: 121)[good_categories table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqiwW.png)
5. retail_category(count rows: 10)[retail_category table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dM208.png)

My Indexes:

1. Date -->reciept.date  #1
2. reciept_goods_index  --> reciept_goods.recieptId  #1,
                            reciept_goods.shopId     #2,
                            reciept_goods.goodId     #3
3. category_id  -->good.category_id   #1

I have a next sql request:

```
SELECT 
      R.shopId, 
      sales, 
      sum(Amount) as sum_amount,       
      count(distinct R.id) as count_reciept, 
      RC.id,  
      RC.name
   FROM
      reciept R
         JOIN reciept_goods RG
            ON R.id = RG.RecieptId 
            AND R.ShopID = RG.ShopId
            JOIN good G
               ON RG.GoodId = G.id
               JOIN good_categories GC 
                  ON G.category_id = GC.id
                  JOIN retail_category RC
                     ON GC.retail_category_id = RC.id                                        
   WHERE 
      R.date >= '2018-01-01 10:00:00'                               
   GROUP BY 
      R.shopId, 
      R.sales, 
      RC.id
```

Explain this query gives next result:
[Explain query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8Nm1.png)
and execution time = 236sec

if  use `straight_join good ON (good.id = reciept_goods.GoodId )` explain query 
[Explain query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1g5g.png)
and execution time = 31sec

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN ... rest of query
```

I think, that problem in the indexes of my tables, but I don't uderstand how to fix them, can someone help me?

Comment: What percentage of your rows in `reciept` has `date>='2018-01-01 10:00:00'`? Is there a significant number of reciepts that have 0 rows in `reciept_goods`? Also: is 31s ok for you and you just want to know why you need a straight_join there, or what execution time do you need? (I know, it can never be fast enough...)

Comment: every reciept have minimum 1 reciept_goods(on avarage 2), in reciept table I have max date '2018-01-15 20:55:29' and count reciept.date>='2018-01-01 10:00:00' AND reciept.date<='2018-01-15 20:55:29' = 349876. I test it in the test server so I think that in real server with bigger resourses it will be work about 12 sec,

Comment: every day in avarage I have 40000 reciepts

Comment: The thumb rule of Index is to include all columns used in Join conditions and where conditions.

Comment: Ambiguous.  What table is `Amount` in??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With about 2% of your rows in `reciepts` having the correct date, the 2nd execution plan chosen (with straight_join) seems to be the right execution order. You should be able to optimize it by adding the following covering indexes:

```
 reciept(date, sales)
 reciept_goods(recieptId, shopId, goodId, amount)
```

I assume that the column order in your primary key for `reciept_goods` currently is `(goodId, recieptId, shopId)` (or `(goodId, shopId, receiptId)`). You could change that to `recieptId, shopId, goodId` (and if you look at e.g. the table name, you may wanted to do this anyway); in that case, you do not need the 2nd index (at least for this query). I would assume that this primary key made MySQL take the slower execution plan (of course assuming that it would be faster) - although sometimes it's just bad statistics, especially on a test server.

With those covering indexes, MySQL should take the faster explain plan even without `straight_join`, if it doesn't, just add it again (although I would like a look at both executions plans then). Also check that those two new indexes are used in the explain plan, otherwise I may have missed a column.

Comment: I change primary key for      <code>reciept_goods</code> to <code>     recieptId, shopId, goodId</code>. And it helped but only when we use <code>count days <=29</code>. For example:  
     <code>WHERE R.date>='2017-12-01 00:00:00' 
AND R.date<='2017-12-29 23:59:59'  ... rest of query </code>. If  we use interval: WHERE R.date>='2017-12-01 00:00:00' 
AND R.date<='2017-12-30 23:59:59'  ... rest of query Or bigger interval. Explain of this query gives result equals execution time = 236sec

Comment: MySQL sometimes just chooses wrong, although I actually do not see any reason how MySQL could still take this path. Are you maybe using MyISAM instead of InnoDB? Have you verified that you actually changed the primary key (with `show create table reciept_goods`, it also tells you if you use MyISAM)? Could you add the execution plans for short and long date ranges? I assume that using `straight_join` is keeping your query fast, so you have a workaround for your immediate problem? Unrelated, but curious: did changing the pk improve execution speed? Did you add the first index?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are depending on walking through a couple of many:many tables?  Many people design them inefficiently.

[*Here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) I have compiled a list of 7 tips on making mapping tables more efficient.  The most important is use of composite indexes.